# Mapbox GL - how to create polygons for each point on the map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, maps, mapbox

I've been trying to make it work for several days already, and haven't found suitable solution.

I have geojson file with following structure:

`{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ 6.773456,51.227741 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "City":"Düsseldorf",
    "Inhabitants_27_05_1970":671999,
    "Inhabitants_25_05_1987":563531,
    "Inhabitants_09_05_2011":586291
    }
  },
  ...`

And for each of this points I need polygon on the map, like this: http://prntscr.com/ie5lh8

Polygon from screenshot is made with the help of tutorial on mapbox website, but I can't find a way to implement it for my data collection, where I only have 2 coordinates and in my geojson file there is no data for this polygons.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wanting 3D extrusions generated from a lat/lng, not an actual "polygon" on the map.

[Take a look at this example](https://122e4e-mapbox.global.ssl.fastly.net/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-extrusion-floorplan/):
You can pass in your geojson via variables or a URL, and then assign an arbitrary `height` that you find works.